# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.training'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, theano

When I am trying to run this

```
import keras
```

I am getting following **error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-c74e2bd4ca71>", line 1, in <module>
    import keras

  File "/Users/rezwan/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils

  File "/Users/rezwan/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils

  File "/Users/rezwan/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K

  File "/Users/rezwan/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *

  File "/Users/rezwan/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.training import moving_averages

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.training'
```

Already I have installed `Theano`, `Tensorflow` and `Keras` through the following commands:

Theano:

```
Rezwans-iMac:~ rezwan$ pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

Tensorflow:

```
Rezwans-iMac:~ rezwan$ conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6
```

---

```
Rezwans-iMac:~ rezwan$ source activate tensorflow
```

---

```
(tensorflow) Rezwans-iMac:~ rezwan$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.3.0rc2-py3-none-any.whl
```

---

```
(tensorflow) Rezwans-iMac:~ rezwan$ pip3 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

Keras:

```
Rezwans-iMac:~ rezwan$ pip install --upgrade keras
```

Above commands work properly.

But I am getting above error. How can I solve this error?

Comment: Are you using jupyter? Jupyter with conda has a very dirty bug. If you had jupyter installed before installing conda, it will keep pointing to your original python installed and will not point to conda's environments. (Thus will not find updates or libraries that exist only in conda). I haven't found a solution for that besides never installing jupyter without conda.

Comment: It seems that tensorflow supports well python 3.5. Not sure about python 3.6.

Comment: I am using spyder. And my OS is mac@DanielMöller

Comment: Are installing keras for python2 and tensorflow for python3? conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6; pip install --upgrade keras; you should install with pip3

Comment: @CAta.RAy `keras` is in `/Users/rezwan/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras`, there is no issue with python2 visible here

Answer (score 2):

To make sure all libraries are installed, you can use a text file with something like this:

```
jupyter==1.0.0
Keras==2.1.3
numpy==1.15.1
pandas==0.22.0
scikit-learn==0.19.1
scipy==1.0.0
tensorboard==1.10.0
tensorflow==1.10.0
```

Then use pip to install:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

or

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

All libraries will be installed for use in the same python version, in case you have multiple installations.

Answer (score 1):

Your tensorflow installation commands:

```
Rezwans-iMac:~ rezwan$ conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6
Rezwans-iMac:~ rezwan$ source activate tensorflow
(tensorflow) Rezwans-iMac:~ rezwan$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.3.0rc2-py3-none-any.whl
(tensorflow) Rezwans-iMac:~ rezwan$ pip3 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

created and activated a virtual environment called tensorflow. Notice the `(tensorflow)` before `Rezwans-iMac`, indicating that you are inside the newly created virtual environment. Since tensorflow is only installed in this virtual environment, you need to switch into it with

```
source activate tensorflow
```

everytime you want to use tensorflow. You will also need to install other packages that you want to use inside this environment.

Also configure your IDE to use the interpreter in `.../anaconda/env/tensorflow/bin/python`

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading tensorflow to "1.15.2" Solved the issue for me.
Seems like tensorflow doesn't have backword compatibility with